# File upload on load balanced server

Tags: permissions, file-upload, load-balancing

I have a web project that I developed where one of the main functions is uploading files.

All the permissions are based on Windows Authentication. When I first created the project, I didn't realize that it would be on a load balanced server.  Now it's in the environment with the load balanced server and the file upload has become a major issue.

I originally thought that I could just create a virtual directory to a network share that would be the upload folder, however that solution has turned into a permissions nightmare.  I haven't been able to do any successful test runs in the production environment.

So I'm thinking now, my solutions would be to create a service on the servers that checks the upload directory and syncs them up.  The other possible solution I see is to store the files in the database which I've had some issues with in the past.

Does anyone know of a straight forward solution for uploading files to a load balanced server that authenticates using Windows Permissions?

Thanks.

UPDATE - So I have changed the application pools to run through a domain account that has full permissions on the share and the folder itself in the Windows permissions.  The Virtual directory has full privileges in IIS, but I'm still getting the same issue.

One of the things that needs to be done with this is also the ability to create directories, which I think might be tripping me up now.  I'm just using System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory

Any other thoughts on where I could be missing permissions?

Comment: If you said it has "full permissions", I'm not really sure what could be wrong - just make sure that it does, in fact have the "modify" and "write" permission on the directory. If you're using groups to assign NTFS permissions, try using the account directly.

Comment: Also, if you change group membership for a worker process account, you have to restart IIS (not just the web site or app pool) for it to re-authenticate, much like users have to log off and log on.

Comment: You could try using AWS S3 to store your files. I'm running a project on a load-balanced server and placing any user-uploaded files in an S3 bucket. If your website was hosted on AWS servers the store/retrieve operation would be very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI,

The solution to this problem was to do temporary impersonation with a user account that had access to the share, permissions on the folder and permissions on the virtual directory.

When I had initially tried this, I had some mistakes in my impersonation code, then when fixed a bad password was entered so I abandoned this approach.  I had finally tried everything else and came back to this - looks like it's working.

So the answer is impersonation when dealing with network shares as virtual directories it looks like.

Here's the link to the code that made it all happen:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#4

Comment: Why would you use impersonation for this? That means you have to store the credentials somewhere in your app, which is UGLY (IMHO).

Comment: It's marked *accepted* (which doesn't necessarily mean *correct*) because he decided to accept his own answer to his own question. Still ugly.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to avoid storing in a database, I think your next best bet would be the virtual directory solution you already spoke about, though I can see how the permissions issues could very easily get out of hand depending on your setup.

In our production environment, all our distinct sites have their own app pools. The app pools themselves each have their own domain account, which makes managing permissions in the filesystem and in SQL server much easier. Each of these accounts is a member of an IIS WP domain group. On each of the servers in the cluster, the domain IIS WP is a member of the local built-in IIS_WPG group. The IIS configuration is identical on each server in the cluster. The important effect of this is to ensure that a given web application is always running as the same identity regardless of which server in the cluster is being hit.

With the setup I've described, it would be very straightforward to implement the virtual directory solution, though you would still have to worry about other obvious issues like naming collisions and such. If you're still using the default app pool identity setup, I think implementing what I've described will help make your life easier in general when dealing with your cluster configuration.

[This article lists some good advantages and disadvantages to storing in the file system:](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=414)

> **Advantages**
>
> One of the
> main benefits of storing the file on
> disk is that it's very easy to do.
> Just call SaveAs on a FileUpload
> control and you're pretty much done.
>
> Another advantage is that files on
> disk are easy to backup; you just copy
> the files to another location. This
> also makes it easier to do incremental
> backups; files that have already been
> backed up don't need to be copied
> again.
>
> **Disadvantages**
>
> Storing
> your files in the file system has a
> few disadvantages as well. Probably
> the most problematic issue is the
> loosely coupled nature of the files on
> disk. They have no strong relation
> with a record in the database. So,
> when you delete, say, a product from
> the database, you may end up with an
> orphaned product image. There is no
> direct way to do an INNER JOIN between
> the product table and your images
> folder to determine what orphaned
> files you have left. This means that a
> page developer is responsible for
> writing code that deletes the file
> from disk whenever the associated
> database records gets deleted.
>
> Also, to store uploaded files on disk,
> your web server needs permissions to
> write to the file system. This is easy
> to come by when you run your own
> server, but may prove to be more
> problematic in an ISP scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work fine:

1. Create a network account
2. have the application pools of the application on each server run under this account
3. create a folder on a specific server and give this network account rights to it
4. set the folder as a 'share' and give the account rights to the share as well
5. Set all servers to use this directory to store the uploaded files